# Convergent Sequence {$x_n$} in $(R,\mathcal T)$

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

Let $\mathcal T$ be the countable complement topology on $R$ and let $R$ be the set of real numbers. Then can we find a convergent sequence {$x_n$} in $(R,\mathcal T)$ ?

**Attempt :**
Let $(R, \mathcal T )$ be a topological space and $x_n \in R$ a sequence. We say that the sequence $x_n$ converges to $x_0 \in R$ if for every open set $U ⊆ R$ which contains $x_0$ there exists an $n_0 \in N$ such that for all $n \ge n_0$ the points $x_n$ lie in $U$. Then how find a convergent sequence {$x_n$} in $(R,\mathcal T)$ ?

Comment: All constant sequences are convergent.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually constant sequences converge in every topological space, let $\{x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be an eventually constant sequence, that is $x_N=l$ for all $N\ge n_0$, clearly all neighbourhoods of $l$ will contain all the $x_n$ for $n\ge n_0$ so $x_n\to l$.

Now for the more interesting part, suppose $\{x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is not eventually constant and converges to some $l$, consider $V=\Bbb R\setminus\{x_n:x_n\neq l\}$, is $V$ an open neighbourhood of $l$? Does it contain all but finitely many $x_n$? What do you conclude about non constant sequences in a space with the cocountable topology?